RabbitMq Ack total
I wanted to clarify one question that I can not solve, I have deployed Rabbitmq 3.7.11 at high load begins to grow socket mem bytes and propoduyut acked total in queues but consumer is, how can this be fixed or how to correctly diagnose the error ?
The client that reads messages from Rabbitmq is written in java and this problem occurs at the highest load on the server.
I did some reading and started looking at setting the vm_memory_high_watermark, vm_memory_high_watermark_paging_ratio and vm_memory_high_watermark_paging_limit parameters
but I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way, these parameters are currently set by default.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
